# Make the sum of booleans as integers with MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, sorting, sum, boolean

I'm trying to sum booleans (where true means 1 and false -1) in an array for each document in my collection and then sort it.

I'm using MongoDB aggregation pipeline with `$addFields`, `$sum` and `$cond`.

Here's the playground : https://play.db-ai.co/m/XQLKqbkkgAABTFVm

The pipeline :

```
[
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "score": {
        "$sum": {
              "$cond": [
                "$votes.value",
                1,
                -1
              ]
            }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "score": -1
    }
  }
]
```

The collection :

```
[
  {
    "votes": [
      {
        "value": true
      },
      {
        "value": true

      },
      {
        "value": true

      },
      {
        "value": false

      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "votes": [
      {
        "value": true

      },
      {
        "value": true

      },
      {
        "value": false

      },
      {
        "value": false

      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Actual results :

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("000000000000000000000000"),
    "votes": [
      {
        "value": true
      },
      {
        "value": true
      },
      {
        "value": true
      },
      {
        "value": false
      }
    ],
    "score": 1
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("000000000000000000000001"),
    "votes": [
      {
        "value": true
      },
      {
        "value": true
      },
      {
        "value": false
      },
      {
        "value": false
      }
    ],
    "score": 1
  }
]
```

What I want :

```
[{
    "_id": ObjectId("000000000000000000000000"),
    "votes": [
      {
        "value": true
      },
      {
        "value": true
      },
      {
        "value": true
      },
      {
        "value": false
      }
    ],
    "score": 2
}, {
 "_id": ObjectId("000000000000000000000001"),
    "votes": [
      {
        "value": true
      },
      {
        "value": true
      },
      {
        "value": false
      },
      {
        "value": false
      }
    ],
    "score": 0
}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve my problem I used `$map` multiple times. The solution of @Plancke is working but I had issues using a `$match` afterwards (it was always giving no results).

```
[
    {
      $addFields: {
        scoresInBoolean: {
          $map: {
            input: '$votes',
            as: 'vote',
            in: '$$vote.value',
          },
        },
      },
    }, {
      $addFields: {
        scoresInInteger: {
          $map: {
            input: '$scoresInBoolean',
            as: 'scoreInBoolean',
            in: {
              $cond: [
                '$$scoreInBoolean',
                1,
                -1,
              ],
            },
          },
        },
      },
    }, {
      $addFields: {
        score: {
          $sum: '$scoresInInteger',
        },
      },
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

I got it to work by unwinding the array and then grouping by _id again.

See Playground: https://play.db-ai.co/m/XQMFlZAtYAABLHtL

```
[
  {
    "$unwind": {
      "path": "$votes"
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "votes": {
        "$push": "$votes"
      },
      "score": { 
        "$sum": {
          "$cond": [
            "$votes.value",
            1,
            -1
          ]
        } 
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "score": -1
    }
  }
]
```